# How to perform multiple page updates behind a single button in XPages

Tags: xpages

This is a high level question but does have specific answers.

I have a requirement where I need to perform an action two times, and update the user with a message before trying the action a second time.  I also want to update the user prior to the first action.

Here is the timeline/sequence of events:

1. User presses button
2. Display message "operation starting"
3. Perform operation
4. If successful, show "operation successful", if operation fails
   show "operation failed - retrying"
5. Retry Operation
6. If successful, show "operation successful", if operation fails show "please try again later".

When I coded this in my java method, the only thing that displayed was the final message.  I tried using `Thread.sleep(1500);` to give the message a chance to display, but **ONLY** the final message will ever be displayed.

I then tried using SSJS to accomplish this task, but the result is the same.  I think I understand why this is happening.

My question is: Is it even possible to do multiple partial refreshes like this.  What is the best approach that I can take to accomplish this requirement.  What workarounds or hacks can anyone think of.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I am on multiple projects, so I will eventually get this working and accept the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to just try twice, you could create an rpc control that does the functionality you want, then call it with a call back

```
    var deferred = service.doSomethingCool();
    deferred.addCallback(function(data) {
  if (data.status == 'error') {
       //set UI Label Fail
       var insideDeferred = service.doSomethingCool();
       insideDeferred.addCallback(function(data) {
       if (data.status == 'error') {
           //set UI Label Fail
        }
        else {
            //set UI Label Success
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This should work for you assuming you have an RPC control named service and method called "doSomethingCool"

Comment: Thanks a ton Toby!  I almost got his working the way I want using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Mark's post for a progress bar once.  http://linqed.eu/?p=174  Didn't get it to work but didn't go deep into the effort.    The solution is probably in there.

What you want should be doable of course.  I would think at the least you use CSJS to do the heavy lifting really.  Have CSJS call SSJS probably via RPC or XAgent and that does all the work of first and secondary message.

I'm just light on the actual details of making that work.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. We can do back and forth client side and server side operations n number of times in a single button click.

1. Create a button with CSJS code for alert.
2. Write SSJS code for your operation.
3. Now the trick is depends on whether your operation is partial or complete refresh.

If partial refresh, use oncomplete / onfailure event in eventhandler to write CSJS code to perform button click operation. Use a hidden input field to store number of retry and to determine at what count the retry has to stop.

If full refresh, oncomplete event does not triggered. Write your CSJS code on clientload event. In this case, Create a hidden input field and bind it to a view scope variable. Use it to store the success or failure in SSJS code and retrieve the value in CSJS code to check and retry.

I have included a sample code with buttons however it can be implemented in many different ways.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="label1">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[alert("operation starting");]]></xp:this.script>
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.status = "first operation completed";
print(getComponent("fail").getValue());}]]></xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[alert("first operation completed. starting second");
document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "False";
document.getElementById("#{id:button2}").click();]]></xp:this.onComplete>
            <xp:this.onError><![CDATA[if ( document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value == "False" ) {
    alert("first operation failed. retry again");
    document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "True";
    document.getElementById("#{id:button1}").click();
} else {
    alert("first operation failed again. starting second");
    document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "False";
    document.getElementById("#{id:button2}").click();
}]]></xp:this.onError>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button2" style="display:none">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="label1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.status = "second operation completed";}]]></xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[alert("second operation completed. starting third");
document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "False";
document.getElementById("#{id:button3}").click();]]></xp:this.onComplete>
            <xp:this.onError><![CDATA[if ( document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value == "False" ) {
    alert("second operation failed. retry again");
    document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "True";
    document.getElementById("#{id:button2}").click();
} else {
    alert("second operation failed again. starting third");
    document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "False";
    document.getElementById("#{id:button3}").click();
}]]></xp:this.onError>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button3" style="display:none">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="label1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.status = "third operation completed";}]]></xp:this.action>
            <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[alert("third operation completed.");
document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "False";]]></xp:this.onComplete>
            <xp:this.onError><![CDATA[if ( document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value == "False" ) {
    alert("third operation failed. retry again");
    document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "True";
    document.getElementById("#{id:button3}").click();
} else {
    alert("third operation failed again. end");
    document.getElementById("#{id:ihRetry}").value = "False";
}]]></xp:this.onError>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:inputHidden id="ihRetry">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA["False"]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:inputHidden>
    <xp:label value="#{viewScope.status}" id="label1"></xp:label>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a code example of this using partial refresh.

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample code. The ssjs code print(getComponent("fail").getValue()); is for making the operation failure. You may also change the logic of ihRetry to have count instead of true or false to have n number of retry.

Comment: Thank You for the code example.  I am not using alerts but updating a field on the backend.

Comment: The alert is for displaying the stage for demo purpose, You may use the SSJS event where I set viewScope.status to update the field value in back end.